# Is there a python t test for difference?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

Is there a t test in a python package where you can test for difference?
If there is how do you use it?

For example test two vectors:

```
a=np.random.randn(5, 7)
b=np.random.randn(5, 7)
```

I have found the t test : ttest_ind in statsmodels. 
However I would like to specify the difference to test for, this can not be passed into the ttest_ind function. Does anybody know another way to do this?

Comment: Actually , I would like to test for a specifyed difference between the two independent samples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ttest_ind` in statsmodels has a `value` option, to test the null hypothesis that the difference between the two means is equal to `value`

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ttest_ind.html