# How to perform a two sample t test in python using any statistics library similar to R?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, t-test

I can do this in R for 2 sample T-test:

```
t.test(x, y = NULL, alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"), mu = 0, 
       paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95)
```

I want some function where I can pass this mu(difference in mean) parameter in Python ttest?

Answer (score 2):

R has one function `t.test()` to perform the Student's T test, while Python employs more methods.

If you want to perform a **one sample t-test** with mu as the true mean μ of the population from which the data is sampled, you should use `scipy.stats.ttest_1samp` and pass the parameter through *popmean*.
Docs are [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_1samp.html).

If you want to perform a **two sample t-test** with mu as the difference in means, `statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ttest_ind` from the `statsmodels` module is the right function, with mu passed through *value*.
Docs are [here](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ttest_ind.html), as well as a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682795/is-there-a-python-t-test-for-difference) to a useful answer.

Other links you may find useful are these:

- https://plot.ly/python/t-test/ - T-tests with plotly
- https://towardsdatascience.com/inferential-statistics-series-t-test-using-numpy-2718f8f9bf2f
  T-test using Python and Numpy
- https://pythonfordatascience.org/independent-t-test-python/ - T-test
  | Python for Data Science

Comment: I have seen this function but I cannot pass the true value( or True difference) mu to this function

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal with the parameter 'popmean', which is the true mean μ of the population from which the data is sampled.

Comment: popmean is there for 1 sampple ttest, but it's not present in two sample ttest

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal ok, so you want to test for difference. It wasn't clear from the question. The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682795/is-there-a-python-t-test-for-difference

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal the function you need is here: http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ttest_ind.html

Comment: Thank you so much, I was using rpy2 till now!

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal I'll edit the answer. So it'll be more precise.

Comment: Sure, I'll also clarify the question.

Comment: how can I do a one-sided (one tail) paired t test in python ? this https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_rel.html is always two sided.

Comment: @serafeim here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984221/how-to-perform-two-sample-one-tailed-t-test-with-numpy-scipy